# How to replicate proc mixed sas code to R programming

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate SAS code with R code.
New to R programming. Could you please help me on the below SAS code

```
ODS output solutionf=sol2;
Proc Mixed data=conc14; 
by subject period   ; 
class subject  period   ; 
model Concentration2 = hr /cl alpha=0.05 solution;
random intercept/subject=subject type=un;
run;
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Does anything here help? https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=sas+proc+mixed+lme4